# ReorderableListView.builder is not reorder

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Mainpage extends StatefulWidget {
 const Mainpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
   _MainpageState createState() => _MainpageState();
  }

 class _MainpageState extends State<Mainpage> {
   @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(color: Colors.white, child: const Cards());
}
}

class Cards extends StatefulWidget {
 const Cards({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<Cards> createState() => _CardsState();
}

class _CardsState extends State<Cards> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
List<String> list = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6',
'7',
'8',
'9',
'10',
];

 return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: ReorderableListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex--;
          }
          final String item = list.removeAt(oldIndex);
          list.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          key: ValueKey(index),
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 19,
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Text(list[index]),
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: list.length,
    ));
}
}
```

The list values are getting an update when I drag. But the state does not rebuild. list values are reordered correctly. But the Reorded list is not working. I try with both ReorderableListView.builder and ReorderableListView. This is my full code. I don't where I made mistake. This is my full code. Someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Declare your list outside from build context. And follow the answer.

Comment: It's work Thank You... But I need to use both reorderlistview.builder and draggable. Eg: I need to drag a specific list value to another location, not an inside list. wrap the text container with a draggable widget but its widget is not dragged.

Comment: Good jobs. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

change your setState

```
setState(() {
            if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
              newIndex -= 1;
            }
              final String item = _products.removeAt(oldIndex);
              list.insert(newIndex, item);

          });
```

Comment: Still, this is not work

Comment: updated my answer, because your condition is also false for the right to left

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**
After looking at the full code you added it appears you're declaring the list at the beginning of the build method of your widget. The list is reset to its initial values each time your widget is rebuild.

Move the list declaration at the beginning of the class :

```
class Cards extends StatefulWidget {
  const Cards({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  List<String> list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];
```

**END OF EDIT**

The problem is in this part of your code:

```
if (oldIndex > newIndex) {
  newIndex = newIndex - 1;
  final String item = list.removeAt(oldIndex);
  list.insert(newIndex, item);
}
```

**It updates the list only if the item is dragged from right to left**. And while doing it, it shifts the new item index by 1 to the left.

What you probably want to do is updating the list every time a drag occurs. And since you'll be deleting the old item before adding the new one you want to decrement newIndex **if the drag is from left to right**.

The code should be :

```
onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex){
  setState(() {
    if (oldIndex < newIndex){
      newIndex--;
    }
    final String item = list.removeAt(oldIndex);
    list.insert(newIndex, item);
  });
}
```

Comment: No, it's not working. Still, I have a issue.

Comment: Can you give more details on your issue? 'State does not rebuild' doesn't really mean anything. 'reorder list is not working' neither when we don't know what reordering you're trying to achieve. What happens with the code I provided that does not statisfy your need?

Comment: List<String> list = [
      '1',
      '2',
      '3',
      '4',
      '5',
      '6',
      '7']; This is my list. I wrap reorderlist builder with container.  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]); My screen orientation in landscape left.

Comment: full code I update in the top. The list gets update in onReorder when I drag. but inside the itembuilder list is not change.

Comment: It's always easier to spot the problem when the code is shared. I updated my answer with the reason your code doesn't work.

Comment: then what to do. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes, just read the EDIT section in my answer. I explained what you should do :  >Move the list declaration at the beginning of the class

Comment: It's work Thank You... But I need to use both reorderlistview.builder and draggable. Eg: I need to drag a specific list value to another location, not an inside list. I wrap the text container with a draggable widget but its widget is not dragged.

Comment: There is already a lot going with this question. For clarity, if my answer resolved your initial question you should mark it as accepted and ask another question. Try to make it the more detailed possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to leave this here for me it's the key to the ReorderableListView
So make sure that key is unique each time

> key: Key("item$index"),